# background process & timing setings in android

Tags: android

I am making one app in android. This is always running in background and 5 min then to print one code. that time application is not shown user and that all process in backgroung. Please help me.
How to solve this problem.

```
package com.finalapp;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    MainActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            for(int i=0 ;i<=2000000;i++)
            {
                try {
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    Log.d("final timer",""+ i);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });



}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

}


Please tell me how to make this application. For working in background.

Always print this number in background.


Please help me.
```

Comment: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidServices/article.html check out this

Comment: please check it http://www.heypasteit.com/clip/0Z4G

Comment: You may find it useful to read about the AlarmManager http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Write your ui thread update logic inside the runnable as shown:

```
YourActivity.this.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
//paste your ui thread logic here

                    }
                });
```

Comment: @user2749218 - please do not badger someone to quickly accept your answer, especially when it is such a low-quality answer that only addresses a small part of the problem.